# Highcharts Treemap Exporting

Tags: highcharts

I'm having difficulties in exporting a Highcharts Treemap. If i drill into a leaf it still export the image of the upper level.

the data structure is as following:

- __ level 1 - suppliers
- _________ level 2 - chemicals
- ______________ level 3 - leafs

code:

```
$(function () {

    var data = [
        {"name":"Supplier A","id":"0","color":"#058DC7"},
        {"name":"Chemical A","id":"0_0","parent":"0"},
        {"name":"leaf","id":"0_0_0","value":222,"parent":"0_0"},
        {"name":"Chemical B","id":"0_1","parent":"0"},
        {"name":"leaf","id":"0_1_0","value":10,"parent":"0_1"},
        {"name":"Supplier B","id":"1","color":"#50B432"},
        {"name":"Chemical C","id":"1_0","parent":"1"},
        {"name":"leaf","id":"1_0_0","value":555,"parent":"1_0"},
        {"name":"Chemical D","id":"0_2","parent":"0"},
        {"name":"leaf","id":"0_2_0","value":777,"parent":"0_2"},
        {"name":"Chemical E","id":"0_3","parent":"0"},
        {"name":"leaf","id":"0_3_0","value":888,"parent":"0_3"},
        {"name":"Supplier C","id":"2","color":"#ED561B"},
        {"name":"Chemical F","id":"2_0","parent":"2"},
        {"name":"leaf","id":"2_0_0","value":1000,"parent":"2_0"}];


    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({  
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            series: [{
                type: "treemap",
                layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
                allowDrillToNode: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
               },
               levelIsConstant: false,
               levels: [{
                   level: 1,
                   dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                   },
                   borderWidth: 3
               }],
               data: data
           }],
           subtitle: {
               text: 'Click points to drill down'
           },
           title: {
                text: 'Treemap Chart'
           }
    });

});
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Example at jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s1vzj9hu/1/

Environment: Linux/Google Chrome/Firefox, Windows/IE

Second level (Chemicals) picture form Export:
[image]

Expected picture as in Web Browser/Monitor

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite experiencing your problem in your JSFiddle. If drilling to level 2 or 3 I get that levels "image" exported, but I'm getting the top level label. Are you not experiencing this?

Comment: Hi Ondkloss i added two pictures to better describe it, also tried it in windows and linux. Yes im getting the top label when exporting, as you can see in the first picture, but i was expecting it to be like the second image. Are my expectations wrong? should nt i expect the second image, when im on the second level (chemicals)?

Comment: No, just sounded like you got the top level image as if no drilling had been done. Images helped, and this is similar to what I'm experiencing.

Comment: The issue is now reported - https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4136